# Hide div using custom attribute data-label in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to hide this div based on its data-label value means the div which is having **data-label="LBL_VIDEO_URL"** is to be hide on call of java-script function.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 label" data-label="LBL_VIDEO_URL">
</div>
```

Comment: `$('[data-label="LBL_VIDEO_URL"]').hide()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very simple

```
//with jQuery
$('div[data-label="LBL_VIDEO_URL"]').hide()

//with Javascript
document.querySelector('div[data-label="LBL_VIDEO_URL"]').style.display='none';
```